# client.get_all_emojis generator returns None

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I've been having a nightmare since yesterday in having this to work, i've tried two methods in getting a string with an emoji object, first doing it manually since I already have the IDs, or using the client.get_all_emojis generator which seems to be more reliable in case there is an ID change in future updates, and it's a little easier

But for whatever reason, it returns a string of None, I checked to make sure the name is correct, this is a default Discord emoji so it's not unique per server, everyone has it, on top of that the bot is in the same role as other bots who can post emojis so at this point, I have no idea what the problem is, here is the code:

```
e = get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='regional_indicator_c')
await client.add_reaction(message, e)
```

Help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_all_emojis` only returns the custom emojis the bot can see.  To transmit the regular unicode emojis (the ones available by default in Discord), you need to send the appropriate unicode character.

```
await client.add_reaction(message, '')  # Not c,
```

or using `\N` escapes:

```
await client.add_reaction(message, '\N{Regional Indicator Symbol Letter C}')
```